next-intl, slug in front of locale
I am about to use next-intl but I wonder if it's possible to do the following:
Instead of using:
.../locale/brand-here/...

Using the following url format, locale after another slug:
.../brand-here/locale/...

It would be awesome if something like this could be achieved while still supporting all of the features provided by next-intl.
